# Creating a link on a class div?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Got a relatively easy question (or so I think), but I'm just a novice at coding.

I have a hexagon grid on my page, and I need to put a different image and link on each.
Problem being that I can't figure out where to place my link.

I've managed to place the images through CSS by manipulating the "red" class that I initially made as placeholder (first HTML line there I have "red1" class where I specified my image).

For placing the links I'm lost. Any help is much appreciated, and bear with me if I've left out important information.

Here's my code so you guys can get what I mean:

```
HTML: <section class="hex clearfix">
        <div class="hex-grid-top">
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red1"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hex-grid-mid">
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hex-grid-bot">
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
            <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red"></div></div></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
     .hexagon {
     overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
        transform: rotate(120deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hexagon-in1 {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
        transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon-in2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
            transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon-in2:hover {
}


.hexagon-scale {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.red1 {
    background-image: url(../Images/thumbs/001-thumb.gif);
        width: 50;
    height: 50;

}





.hex {
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}

.hex-grid-top {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 55px -105px 55px;
}

.hex-grid-mid {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto -105px auto;
}

.hex-grid-bot {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 55px;
}

.hex-grid-top .hexagon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.hex-grid-mid .hexagon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px;

}

.hex-grid-bot .hexagon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

So as I said, I'd like to know how to add links to these hexagons!
And if the ONLY way I can do that is to attach the images differently then so be it.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Edit: Thanks VLS, that works perfectly! I'm afraid I'm not sure why it works, but it does!

Comment: Couldn't you just absolute-positions the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the links inside your inner hexagon div, then styling like this:

```
.hexagon-in2 a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    top: 40px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/z9Ver/ (I commented out `cursor: pointer` for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

Try wraping your `div`s in a `link tag` like so:

```
<a href="your/link/address"><div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"></a>
```

Whenever the div is clicked the link will be too.